# Updateing Ubuntu to version 23.10

Tags: 23.10, app-center

i updated to Ubuntu 23.10 and i cant find the new app center

i have tried snap refresh

some more info that might be helpful

1. i have installed Flatpack
2. my snap version is

   ```
   snap    2.60.4+23.10.1
   snapd   2.60.4+23.10.1
   series  16
   ubuntu  23.10
   kernel  6.5.0-10-generic
   ```
3. i updated from 23.04